# What kind of pumpkin is it?

Tags: identification, pumpkins

I've planted some pumpkins this year from the seeds we've collected from the store bought pumpkins: hokkaido, spaghetti, delicata. At some point the plants got all mixed up, so I didn't know which is which, but as this one was growing I was sure it's spaghetti pumpkin, since it's gotten so big and oval. But then, instead of turning yellow (like I remember the original fruit looked like) it turned dark green. It kind of have the delicata's shape, but definitely not the delicata's size and I've pollinated the last fruit by hand with the same plant's flower. All fruits look identical...  What kind of pumpkin can this be?

It has 3 fruits now and I'm not sure if I can already harvest it and if it's even edible XD. Another pumpkin, in the garden, has also grown fruits. It looked very similar until recently, but the pumpkins outside are turning yellow now and look like the actual spaghetti pumpkins from a store.

Here is an image of the whole plant (it grew in the glasshouse by an accident, but I decided to just go with it):
[image: whole pumpkin plant]

Here is the fruit while growing:
[image: pumpkin fruit]

And here is its current state:
[image: ripe fruit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The squash/pumpkin family freely interbreed; so, because you planted collected seed, it is pot luck.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know! But it can't have different breeds inside one fruit, can it? I though those seeds were collected from only one spaghetti pumpkin, but we ended up with this plant with green fruits and another one with smooth yellow-ish ones...

Comment: I think one flower can be pollinated by several other plants so a variety of seedlings are possible from one fruit.